# Change Speed Before Ctrl+C with Region Selected activates The Copy Command Instead of Allowing Other Commands On Region

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, cua, cua-mode

Is there a way to change the speed before the copy command executes when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with CUA bindings set. If you press it fast enough you can execute commands on the region and the copy command is ignored. This setting is quite fast and I would prefer it to wait a bit longer if possible. Just wondering if anyone knows how to change this or where this is controlled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use CUA, but it's probably `cua-prefix-override-inhibit-delay`:

> If non-nil, time in seconds to delay before overriding prefix key. If
>   there is additional input within this time, the prefix key is used as
>   a normal prefix key.  So typing a key sequence quickly will inhibit
>   overriding the prefix key. As a special case, if the prefix keys
>   repeated within this time, the first prefix key is discarded, so
>   typing a prefix key twice in quick succession will also inhibit
>   overriding the prefix key. If the value is nil, use a shifted prefix
>   key to inhibit the override.